# SSO: 2 projects: automatically login in the second project

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, single-sign-on, cross-site

I have to projects: my own, let's call it Intranet and the second one: MVCForum (http://mvcforum.com).
The goal: when user login to my intranet and click a link to the forum - he is automatically redirected and login.

What I have done till now, is I can send the data (user login + password) to the LogOn method in MVCForum MembersController. It goes very nice, everything seems exactly the same as when I normally log in to the forum. But some how after being redirected (from the logon page in forum to the main site in forum) I am not logged in :(

I' spent last 3 days getting with this and nothing.
intranet: localhost:55123
forum: localhost:9666
There is one database for the Forum and another one for the Intranet: not connected to each other - for now I will leave this.

Both projects are in one solution.
 Here is my code:
1. My redirect to forum (in one of the intranet controllers):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Forum()
    {

        string url = "http://localhost:9666/Members/Logon";
        Uri address = new Uri(url);
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                           {
                               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserName", "admin"),
                               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "password"),
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("RememberMe", "False")
                           };

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieJar,
            UseCookies = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = address
        };


        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        var responseCookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(uri);
        foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
        {
            cookieJar.Add(cookie);
            string cookieName = cookie.Name;
            string cookieValue = cookie.Value;
            this.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value){Domain = cookie.Domain, Expires = cookie.Expires});
        }

        var person = new Person { Name = "name1" };

        var mod = new LogOnViewModel
                      {
                          Password = "password",
                          RememberMe = false,
                          ReturnUrl = null,
                          UserName = "admin"
                      };


        return this.Redirect("http://localhost:9666/"); 
    }
```

2. web.config of intranet:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
         protection="Validation"
         path="/"
         domain="localhost"/>
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="D4499A4E3540646431DAFBA7462C3A8220447D7C49DEA6F6A2DD94D9A400DBBEBDC8020856FD91B353087716C3E320902508249FEDA4F10E517F799669ADA762"
         decryptionKey="897B17754EB63518A45E9C209B7ADD542B5D09B4D2ED03C024EF07E4BF169387"
         validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1"/>
```

3. The logon method in MVCForum:

   public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnViewModel model)
       {
           using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkManager.NewUnitOfWork())
           {
               var username = model.UserName;
               var password = model.Password;

   ```
           try
           {
               if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                   var message = new GenericMessageViewModel();
                   var user = new MembershipUser();
                   if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(username, password, System.Web.Security.Membership.MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts))
                   {
                       // Set last login date
                       user = MembershipService.GetUser(username);
                       if (user.IsApproved && !user.IsLockedOut)
                       {
                           FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, model.RememberMe);
                           HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),false,user.Id.ToString() )));

                           Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                           user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

                           if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl) && model.ReturnUrl.Length > 1 && model.ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                               && !model.ReturnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !model.ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                           {
                               return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                           }

                           message.Message = LocalizationService.GetResourceString("Members.NowLoggedIn");
                           message.MessageType = GenericMessages.success;

                           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = string.Empty });
                       }

                   }

                   // Only show if we have something to actually show to the user
                   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Message))
                   {
                       TempData[AppConstants.MessageViewBagName] = message;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     (...)
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           finally
           {
               try
               {
                   unitOfWork.Commit();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   unitOfWork.Rollback();
                   LoggingService.Error(ex);
               }

           }

           return View(model);
       }
   }
   ```
4. The web.config of the MVCForum project:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/members/logon" timeout="2880"  name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
         protection="Validation"
         path="/"
         domain="localhost"/>
</authentication>
<machineKey validationKey="D4499A4E3540646431DAFBA7462C3A8220447D7C49DEA6F6A2DD94D9A400DBBEBDC8020856FD91B353087716C3E320902508249FEDA4F10E517F799669ADA762"
          decryptionKey="897B17754EB63518A45E9C209B7ADD542B5D09B4D2ED03C024EF07E4BF169387"
          validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1"/>
```

I don't really understand why it is not working. Don't know what other code could be helpful. The machineKey and cookie name are thesame because I read that it must be thesame so I can achieve what I want.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Even if this works, it is fundamentally flawed - you are reinventing an SSO protocol on your own where sending username/password between sites sounds like a potential security hole. Instead, use any mature existing SSO protocol like OAuth2 or WS-Federation. This will benefit in many ways, including endless possibilities of federating with other identity providers / consumers.

Comment: Well...to be honest I don't really know how to use this OAuth2.. I've found some info and read an article, but I don't really see how it works and how I should use it to solve my problem :(